# Shortcode wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Boa tarde, preciso fazer um shortcode no wordpress para que o mesmo mostre a versão do meu programa no rodapé do site, ao lado do copyrigth.

Preciso fazer utilizar um hook? alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: API para geração de shortcode: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API - Wizard para simplificar o processo: https://generatewp.com/shortcodes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um [action hook](http://hookr.io/actions/get_template_part_slug/) diretamente no seu template para adicionar a versão.

No meu exemplo o copyrigth está no arquivo footer-copyrigth.php

Então utilizei o hook da seguinte maneira = `add_action( 'get_template_part_template-parts/footer-copyright', $version, 'version_footer', 10, 2 );`